# JQuery delay before fadeOut

Tags: jquery, delay

I have written a jquery script that allows me to fade divs in and out, then repeat. The code works fine. However, when I try to add a delay (I want the div to stay up a few seconds before fading out), it does not work properly. I've tried adding the delay in several places inside the code and none seem to function properly. I am using Jquery version 1.9.1

**Here is the script that I have written:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ShowPostDiv(0);
});

function ShowPostDiv(divIndex)
{
    $(".home_entry_txt").hide();

    if(divIndex >= $(".rotate_hide").length)
    {
        divIndex = 0;
    }
    var divPostHtml = $(".rotate_hide:eq("+divIndex+")").html();
    $(".home_entry_txt").html(divPostHtml); 
    $(".home_entry_txt").fadeIn(3000, function(){
             $(".home_entry_txt").fadeOut("slow");
        });
    divIndex++;
    setTimeout("ShowPostDiv("+divIndex+")", 4000);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried $(".home_entry_txt").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow"); ?

Comment: As a side note, you should use an anonymous function with setTimeout, rather than a string. So, `setTimeout(function() { ShowPostDiv(divIndex); }, 4000);`

Answer (score 45):

You can just write

```
$(".home_entry_txt").fadeIn(3000).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried .delay()?
something like:

```
$(".home_entry_txt").fadeIn().delay(200).queue(function(next) {
$(".home_entry_txt").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ShowPostDiv(0);
});

function ShowPostDiv(divIndex)
{
    $(".home_entry_txt").hide();

    if(divIndex >= $(".rotate_hide").length)
    {
        divIndex = 0;
    }
    var divPostHtml = $(".rotate_hide:eq("+divIndex+")").html();
    $(".home_entry_txt").html(divPostHtml); 
    $(".home_entry_txt").fadeIn(3000, function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".home_entry_txt").fadeOut("slow");
        },4000);
    });
    divIndex++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Trying this caused it to fade in, stay a while, then fade out. This is what I want. However, it does not repeat with the next div. How would I get it to repeat again for the next div to fade in, stay a while, then fade out?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by the next div?