# How to make a div element fade away

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and I'm working with a Rails web app. It has an "Order" button, and when I click it, it says: "Thank you for ordering". It's done using the flash action. I would like the message to fade away after 5 seconds. I added this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#notice").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

This script is inside the views/layout folder and is linked to the application.html.erb file inside the same folder. However, it is not working. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686598/jquery-delay-before-fadeout

Comment: what is not working, fading out after 5 seconds?

Comment: The fadeOut event should be triggered only after the message shows up. With your code, the browser just tries to fade out the #notice element as soon as the page is loaded. Besides, the way it is, it would fade the element immediately, with no delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have to do couple things to make it happens. Here is what I would do.

1. Add a `div` with an `id` and hide it.

   `<div id="notice" style="display: none"> Thank you for your ordering </div>`
2. Add script.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function note() {
       $("#notice").fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();
   });
   ```
3. Add `onclick` function to  `.erb` file.

   `<%= link_to "Order", order_path, :onclick=>'function note()'  %>`

Hopefully it will help.

P.S. You also can skip step 2 and add the script directly into the .erb file.

```
<%=
  link_to "Order", order_path, :onclick=>'$("#notice").fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut();'
%>
```